# Dynamic Twitter Share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Here's the code that extracts the Title and the URL of the current page and shares it on twitter.

I need help adding @TwitterHandle after the title text and couldn't get it to work so it reads while sharing: "Title URL @TwitterHandle"

Would appreciate your quick input. Thanks.

```
<script>
function tweetCurrentPage()
{ window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url="+escape(window.location.href)+"&text="+document.title, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false; }
</script>

<a class="tweet" href="javascript:tweetCurrentPage()" target="_blank" alt="Tweet this page"><span>Tweet</span></a>
```

Comment: Please use quotes consistently, either use double quotes ``" `` or use single quotes ``'``, but don't mix and match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter handle needs to be passed as the part of the `text` URL parameter. Please refer the below code snippet.

```
<script>
var twitterHandle = 'sarbbottam';

function tweetCurrentPage() {
    window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url='+escape(window.location.href)+'&text='+document.title + ' via @' + twitterHandle, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
    return false; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should accept the answer, if it has served the purpose :)

Comment: i thought i did!! haha.. sorry dude. its done now :)

Comment: btw, any idea how to shorten the URL? Currently it is showing something like http://website.com/post-topic/content-writing/my-topic-discussion/

Comment: That will not be possible with JavaScript, you need to use some url-shortener service. BTW, when the tweet will be posted, twitter will automatically shorten the URL.